# GPU Drivers not working on AWS Ubuntu Deep Learning AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, pytorch, gpu, ec2-ami

It seems as though GPU drivers do not seem to work on the Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 180.04) g4dn.xlarge instances I have set up for the past few hours. `nvidia-smi` gives output:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

and `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `false`.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Most probably you had a inconsistent driver installation. purge nvidia & cuda and retry.

Comment: This issue has been resolved in the Deep Learning AMI v28+ (release notes here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/appendix-ami-release-notes.html)

Comment: I seem to have a similar issue with the Base version of the AMI, v32, when sometimes (maybe one instance out of 20) the GPU is not found - X server says `(EE) No devices detected.` and the likes of `(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory`. This then causes the driver to now be loaded and nvidia-docker to not work, and everything goes downhill from there :-(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? i have the same problem.

Comment: You can choose a GPU enabled image type along with GPU enabled instance type and then you don't need to set up the CUDA drivers:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-images.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html